# Why is this a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

In class the professor said that

f(x)-->g(x)*f(x) is considered a linear transformation.  I don't understand why that is, can someone explain?

Comment: This question is hard to understand. It will help if you say who $f$ and $g$ are, and give some context.

Comment: The professor did not even define f(x) and g(x).  He simply wrote that: f(x) maps g(x)*f(x) is a linear transformation.

Comment: I would've expected something more like $f(cx+dy)=cf(x)+df(y)$ where $c,d$ are constants. Or at least that's what I learned a linear transformation was!

Comment: that is why i am extremely confused. i do not understand how to even implement the two rules to verify that this is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Your domain is the "vector space of functions", . You didn't specify what functions but it could be something like the space of continuous real valued functions defined on the real line. This is an infinite dimensional vector space. The functions themselves can be wildly non-linear but this doesn't make your professor's statement false.

The linear operator is multiplication by the function g, which again could be a continuous real valued functions defined on the same domain. Multiplication by g would just give you another real valued function. This result is linear in f, i.e. g(x)*(c1*f1(x) + c2*f2(x)) = c1*g(x)*f1(x) + c2*g(x)*f2(x).

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be the set of all functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Fix $g\in V$.  Then $f\mapsto g\cdot f$ is a linear transformation $V\to V$ because it satisfies both axioms of linearity: For all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,f'\in V$, we have:

$$g\cdot(f+f') = g\cdot f + g\cdot f'$$

$$g\cdot(c\cdot f) = c\cdot (g\cdot f)$$

Comment: $f'$ is probably a bad choice of notation...

Comment: @symplectomorphic The bad choice of notation was $f$ for a variable, $g$ for a constant.  This should be $u\cdot (f+g)$ or something.

Comment: Nah. I'm saying it would be too easy for a beginner to misconstrue $f'$ as the derivative, which also shows up in discussions of linear maps on function spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think your professor was trying to state that multiplication by a function $g$ is a linear operation in a function space (or between to function spaces).
For example, consider the space $C(\mathbb R)$ of continuous functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.
It is a vector space.
Now fix any continuous function $g$.
Then the map $f\mapsto gf$ (pointwise product) is a linear transformation $C(\mathbb R)\to C(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but perhaps it refers to the left translation map by $g(x)$ which is a linear operator. More precisely, let $A$ be any $K$-algebra with underlying vector space $V$ and consider the map $L(x)\colon y\mapsto xy$. This is an endomorphism of $V$.

Comment: This is perfectly correct, but I somehow believe that this is not the level of abstraction the OP is familiar with or the professor meant. My guess is that the question is about real valued functions on a subset of the reals, but I could be mistaken.